# Problems with moving character in python game and other issues

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a pygame game and the player does not always move to the arrow keys I press. Here is the code for moving the player.

```
def playerstuff(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.XChange = 3
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.XChange = -3
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.TownYChange = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.TownYChange = 5
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.XChange = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.XChange = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.TownYChange = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.TownYChange = 0
    if self.TownYChange != 0:
        self.TownY += self.TownYChange
        gameDisplay.blit(Town,(0,self.TownY))
    self.Xpos += self.XChange
    gameDisplay.blit(Town,(self.Xpos,self.Ypos),pygame.Rect(self.Xpos,self.Ypos,40,50))
    gameDisplay.blit(Idle_man,(self.Xpos,self.Ypos))
    pygame.display.update()
```

This is the code that makes the level and does some other things

```
def game():         
    gameDisplay.blit(Town,(0,0))
    player1 = Player(width/2,height/2 - 20)
    while True:
        player1.playerstuff()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.update()
```

I also am having a problem with this line:

```
gameDisplay.blit(Town,(self.Xpos,self.Ypos),pygame.Rect(self.Xpos,self.Ypos,40,50))
```

I wanted to use this line to delete the character and redraw him.
The line does what I want it to do but it fills the space around the player with gray when I step on a green part of the background.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably throwing away events in your global event queue. You check the event queue twice, once in `playerstuff()` and once in your global game loop, but the second time you don't deal with keypress events.

```
def game():         
    gameDisplay.blit(Town,(0,0))
    player1 = Player(width/2,height/2 - 20)
    while True:
        player1.playerstuff() # you check the event queue in this method already
        for event in pygame.event.get():
        # gets all the events that are currently in the queue, meaning all
        # that occured since you last checked the queue in playerstuff()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            # if event.type was a keypress, you dismiss the event here, 
            # causing you to "lose" keystrokes
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.update()
```

The solution is to only have one global event queue and handle all keypresses there.

Comment: Thank you but I was also wondering how to fix my other problems

Comment: Your blitting problem is a completely different issue and should go into its own post. If you can provide some screenshots and a minimal working example, I'm happy to take a look.